# Conversion from DateTime (Joda Time) to Date (java.util)

Tags: datetime, date, jodatime

I parse this date "22/11/11" into a DateTime object called s. When I do s.getDayOfMonth() it gives me 22 which is right. However, when I convert the DateTime object to a Date object and try to get the date using s.toDate().getDate() it returns 24 which is not right. Does anyone have an idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Pls copy the relevant code. Further, what do you see if you print s.toDate() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Joda-Time `DateTime.toDate()` method converts to a `java.util.Date` with the same millisecond instant. The `java.util.Date.getDate()` method uses the local default time-zone to return its value, whereas `DateTime.getDayOfMonth()` uses the time-zone stored in the `DateTime` object. If the two time-zones are different, you may see a difference, explaining the 22/24 you observe.

To understand further, print the time-zone of the `DateTime`, and the default Java zone `TimeZone.getDefault()` used by `java.util.Date`.